# Conditional striking in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, conditional-formatting

[image: New Image][image: Hello All, I need help in Excel where If the length (column A) is Greater or equal to 10 then letter "Y" in column B gets striked out and if its less than 10 letter "N" in column B gets striked out]

Hello All, I need help in Excel where If the length (column A) is Greater or equal to 10 then letter "Y" in column B gets striked out and if its less than 10 letter "N" in column B gets striked out

Comment: Use this formula in conditional formatting, select the last rule and enter `=A2>=10` for `Y` and format with `S̶t̶r̶i̶k̶e̶t̶h̶r̶o̶u̶g̶h̶` but for the `N` do you want to consider the blank cells as well? If yes then `=A2<10` and format with `S̶t̶r̶i̶k̶e̶t̶h̶r̶o̶u̶g̶h̶`, if not let us know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve the required conditional formatting you can follow the steps as is mentioned below:

[image]

---

- Select the range `B2:B9` or adjust the range as per your suit.
- From `Home` Tab --> Under `Styles` Group --> Click `Conditional Formatting` --> Click `New` which opens the `New Formatting Rule` window. (Short Cut to Open --> <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> )
- Now, select the last rule --> `Use a formula to determine which cells to format`
- Enter the below formula in `Edit the Rule Description`

---

```
=(A2>=10)*(B2="Y")
```

---

- Click on `Format` --> Check the `S̶t̶r̶i̶k̶e̶t̶h̶r̶o̶u̶g̶h̶` under `Effects`
- Press `Ok` twice.

---

The above would `S̶t̶r̶i̶k̶e̶t̶h̶r̶o̶u̶g̶h̶`  all those cells in `Column A` greater than or equal to `10` with `Y` in `Column B`, to perform the same for those less than `10` and have `N` in `Column B` repeat the process from steps 1 to 3 and enter the formula and lastly do the formatting, press ok twice. If you don't want to repeat the process, then select the range `Column B` and hit <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> , select the existing rule and hit `Duplicate Rule` and change the formula with the below one.

---

```
=(A2<>"")*(A2<10)*(B2="N")
```

---

**Note** that this would `S̶t̶r̶i̶k̶e̶t̶h̶r̶o̶u̶g̶h̶`  all `N` in `Column B` with values less than `10` but will ignore the ones with blank cells in `Column A` but if you want to consider the blanks then the above would be.

```
=(A2<10)*(B2="N")
```

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

### EDIT: 6/26/2023

Per OP's Comments:

> *I have uploaded a new screenshot for your reference, where I have grouped every length with a Y & N, indicating there's a Y & a N for
> every individual length number in "Column A" and that if the length is
> less than 10 it should strike only N (as shown in B5 of the new
> screenshot, Since A4 is less than 10 I have striked N) the new
> screenshot is what I the result should look like.*

---

• Formula used :

Green :

```
=(LOOKUP(2,1/(A$2:A2<>""),A$2:A2)<10)*(B2="N")
```

---

Blue:

```
=(LOOKUP(2,1/(A$2:A2<>""),A$2:A2)>=10)*(B2="Y")
```

---

Note that color fill only used to identify. You can ignore the color fill.

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

Comment: Hello Mayukh, this indeed is helpful and I really appreciate the efforts you have put. But for some reason the numbers greater than 10 are striking both Y and N. while I want values >= 10 to strike only Y and anything less than 10 to strike N (which is working perfect) any inputs?

Comment: @starkfrau please check I have posted a .gif refer kindly

Comment: There's 1 Y and 1 N for every given length & the blanks in column A stay as it is. So if A2 is 10 it should only strike Y. Alternatively, if A2 is 5 it should strike only N.

Comment: But you have shown a different screenshot in your post. Can you update your post please.

Comment: different screenshot? As in?

Comment: I meant to say, can you show me, what you are expecting as you have said, because in the post what you have said based on that the solution was posted, presently what you are saying I am not able to relate, it will help me to understand more clearly, kindly show me the expected output by doing it manually.

Comment: I have uploaded a new screenshot for your reference, where I have grouped every length with a Y & N, indicating there's a  Y & a N for every individual length number in "Column A" and that if the length is less than 10 it should strike only N (as shown in B5 of the new screenshot, Since A4 is less than 10 I have striked N) the new screenshot is what I the result should look like.

Comment: @starkfrau if you had mentioned about the grouping part in the beginning then i would have posted accordingly, misunderstood the question in the beginning.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much for your help.  I really appreciate how prompt you have been in solving my queries!

Comment: @starkfrau glad to know. I really appreciate the patience you have shown thanks.